# How to properly specify font size and face in a classified Ads HTML template?

Tags: html, web-development, css, javascript, ebay

How to properly specify font size and face in a classified Ads HTML template without html, body and head tags (these tags will be cutted), when template will be put in iframe on page? The classifieds website will use mixed styles which will come partly from it page, so every CSS style I don’t assign specifically, will get a style declaration from main website CSS. I know inline style is a good solution for elements, but sometimes adding styles to a wrapper of template is enough. The sample of [html template](http://pastebin.com/dWVzzsM2).

Comment: what you are using for classified ad? any software?

Comment: I mean html template, consisting from tables, some internal CSS and div sections with paragraphs, like `<div id="templatedesc" class="tempwidget"><div class="temp-content"> <p>..</p>`

Comment: you can set like <style=font-size:20px;/>

Answer (score 1):

If you can specify css in the wrapper do it there, if not, inline seems a good option, it works. `<div style="font-size:150%"></div>`

Comment: I can apply style to "temp-content" div: `.temp-content { width:700px; text-align:left; font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;}`